# DB prefix not updating

Tags: database, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a site I built locally and migrated to a live environment. Later I created a copy of this site and booted it up locally again to do some further dev in there. My local dev software (Local by Flywheel) created a fresh DB for the site to run from at this point.

I am now ready to push to production with the new version, and am finding that on uploading the database to the live server, the prefix on all DB tables which existed before (including the `home` and `site_url` values) is reverting to an old sequence, and fetching values from the previous database. No matter what I try and do when I upload the DB it pings back to older values.

Where new tables have been created (e.g. with the addition of a plugin), the prefix is as I expect it to be.

If I open the database via my local install in Sequel Pro, I see the prefixes and values I expect to see – they are correct and they match the contents of the site. However if I open it in Adminer I see the older values, as when I import the DB to the server using PHPMyAdmin.

The only way I have managed to get the production site to work is by manually setting the `home` and `site_url` values in `wp_config.php` as per this article: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php. This feels hacky to me, and not future-proof.

I will have more dev to do in this site over the coming months – I would like to stabilise this issue and get it working like every other WP install I have created, but I cannot figure out what is happening here.

Some basic questions:

1. Is this something people have seen before?
2. Where could the DB be fetching the older values from?
3. Is there a way to consolidate the various pieces of data the site seems to be pulling in to a single new database?

I understand that my question is vague because I don't understand what's happening, and I offer it with apologies for that. I am hoping I've described this well enough for someone to recognise a known mistake or issue. If anyone has time to help me learn something here I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking... You say the database prefix is reverting, which I read as "something is modifying `wp-config.php` to change the configured database table prefix to a previous value," but then you also say you fixed it by setting the home and site URL constants, which has nothing to do with the database prefix

Comment: I'm not surprised it's not clear @bosco – I don't really understand it myself, and I truly appreciate you even humouring me here. Some of the database values I can see in phpmyadmin don't reflect the values in the site, and different tables in the DB have different prefixes. I don't know where, for example, the user info is stored – it's in the site, and it migrated with the site, but it's not in the database. This site has 130+ users, but I only see the dev admin accounts in the DB. So setting the home and site_url constants in `wp-config.php` was simply the only workaround i could find.

Comment: In general setting those constants isn't a bad practice at all - in fact it's pretty common for a dev/staging and production installation of the same site to have a completely different `wp-config.php` file - but usually it's not necessary if the proper serialization-aware search & replace was made on the database during the migration. I have seen something like what you describe with the multiple tables - sometimes migration or synchronization plugins will create a copy of the tables in such a fashion. It really does sound like Sequel Pro/Adminer are accessing two different databases though

Comment: It does. I suspect something has been done being the scenes by the Local software, and that it's somehow referencing more than one DB. That doesn't explain why forcing the contents in `wp-config` would fix the issue though. I'd like to be able to consolidate the various sources of info for the site into one place. I do have different wp-config files for dev, stage and prod – I'm not familiar with the  "proper serialization-aware search & replace" approach..?

Comment: When a site's files and content are moved between domains, for the most part things should "just work". Posts would have GUIDs reflecting the old site in the database, but that doesn't really matter, functionally. However, a lot of plugins and themes are coded in such a manner that they end up storing absolute URLs in the database (or users use absolute URLs in their content), so it's necessary to replace instances of the old site origin with the new one in the database. WP "serializes" structured data into strings for some fields, and if not handled correctly, the S&R can break that data.

Comment: I don't think it's really an issue here - I was mostly just thinking out loud that if a site's site URL and home URL aren't defined in `wp-config.php` but are in the database (as per the setting available in the dashboard), then the S&R operation performed as a part of the common migration procedure should already account for the new site origin - defining those constants isn't normally necessary.

Comment: Yes I've never had to do that before. I always update permalinks and run [this plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) after moving a site, and it usually covers all my needs (there are some cases where an absolute URL needs updating, but usually I have a list of these and just make sure I do it manually). So maybe I'm doing S&R and just not calling it that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127006/discussion-between-bosco-and-mtm).